# Are these two relations the same?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, recurrence-relations, dynamic-programming

Suppose we want to find the shortest path with at most $\ell$ edges in a positive weighted directed graph $G=(V,E)$ with weight $w(u,w)$ on each edge.

According to Jeff Erickson's algorithms textbook, a dynamic programming  approach for the above problem is to use this recurrence relation:

$$\begin{equation}
  d_{u,v}^\ell=\begin{cases}
    w(u,v), & \text{if $\ell=1$}.\\
    \min_{x\in V}(d_{u,x}^{\lceil{\frac{\ell}{2}}\rceil}+d_{x,v}^{\lfloor{\frac{\ell}{2}}\rfloor}), & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

But my question is if we write the above recurrence as

$$\begin{equation}
  d_{u,v}^\ell=\begin{cases}
    w(u,v), & \text{if $\ell=1$}.\\
    \min_{x\in V}(d_{u,v}^{\ell-1},d_{u,x}^{\lceil{\frac{\ell}{2}}\rceil}+d_{x,v}^{\lfloor{\frac{\ell}{2}}\rfloor}), & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

can we conclude that two relations give us an optimal solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think the first recurrence should be $d_{u,v}^l = \min_{x\in V}d_{u,x}^{\lceil\frac{l}{2} \rceil} +d_{v,x}^{\lfloor \frac{l}{2} \rfloor}$ if $l > 1$

$d_{u,v}^l = \min_{x\in V}d_{u,x}^{l-1} + w(x, v)$ is also a correct recurrence, and is the one used in the Bellman Ford algorithm.

The benefit of the first recurrence is that for an all-pairs shortest path, the $l$ is divided by $2$ instead of being decreased by $1$ at each step, which results in only $\log_2(n)$ steps performed instead of $n$.

Comment: Thank you. I resolved the issue in my questions. But is there proof that shows us two recurrences give us the optimal solution?

Comment: @john It is still not correct, you need a plus in your recurrence, to find the shortest path between $u$ and $v$, you need to consider all the possible choice $x$ for the vertex in the middle of a path. (you get a path $u->...->>x->...->v$). The length of this path is the length of the path from $u$ to $x$ plus the length of the path from $x$ to $v$.

Comment: Thank you. I correct it. the second relation has an additional parameter, can it give us a suboptimal answer?

Comment: @john Your second relation does not really make sense. What you are minimizing is a tuple, so there is no clear order of comparison. $d_{u,v}^l$ does not even depend on $x$.

Comment: So can we conclude that the second relation is incorrect?

Comment: Can you explain more why the second doesn't make sense?

Comment: Let's take an example. Suppose you have 3 vertices, so $V=\{1,2,3\}$. Then, if $l=10$, we have $min_{x\in V} (d_{u,v}^{9},d_{u,x}^5+d_{x,v}^5) = min( (d_{u,v}^{9},d_{u,1}^5+d_{1,v}^5), (d_{u,v}^{9},d_{u,2}^5+d_{2,v}^5), (d_{u,v}^{9},d_{u,3}^5+d_{3,v}^5) )$. Lets replace the $d$'s by some values, you end up with something like $min( (3,4), (5,8), (6, 3))$. I can't make sense of what we are minimizing here...